# Swift: Share object between processes

Tags: swift

I need to manage an IO resource (UART telemetry device) that is connected to a computer and multiple processes need to interact with. So the traffic needs to be serialised and eventually prioritised.
The computer resources are extremely limited, so I thought avoiding an IPC/Websocked based "master process" would be good for overall performance.
I was thinking of creating a shared object like a singleton that can be accessed by other processes on the computer. But I don't know how to achieve that and if it's the best way to solve this problem.

This is a rough idea of the object:

```swift
class Telemetry {

    // This should be accessible from multiple processes and auto-created like normal singletons
    static var global: Telemetry = Telemetry()

    let queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "telemetry-queue")
    var ioHandler: IOHandler = IOHandler(port: "/tty0")
    
    func send(data: DataPackage, clientID: UUID) {
        queue.sync { /* data sending logic */ }
    }
    
    func receive(clientID: UUID) -> DataPackage {
        queue.sync { /* read incoming data and return package for client */ }
    }
    
 }

struct DataPackage { }

struct IOHandler {
    init(port: String) {}
}
```

I'm also not sure if swift is the best choice for this task.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Singletons are just a global variable, and like all globals, you have one per process.   To really have one instance for all processes, you'll need it to be another process, which means IPC, but it doesn't need to be networked IPC. If it's running on MacOS, you should look into [XPC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xpc).  If it's running on Linux, a Unix Domain socket or a localhost TCP socket would be traditional ways of doing it.

Comment: As for choice of language, there's no reason you can't do it in Swift.  The only thing is if you are choose to use Unix Domain sockets that will mean using BSD or Linux APIs, which are C APIs, which means using `UnsafePointer` types.  You'll want to contain those in a more Swifty API.

Comment: You say computer resources are "extremely limited".  If you don't mind getting deep in the details, you can roll your own IPC using shared memory.  You can implement exactly what you need, control the server buffer sizes, etc...  It's not a trivial amount of work, but it's not *that* hard.

Comment: @ChipJarred Ok thx. The code will be used on embedded systems with a very light linux version - < 550mb total ram. I never worked with shared memory before, do you have some references/links for this in swift?

Comment: There might be a Swift package on GitHub you could use.  Last time I used the Darwin api for it, I was writing it in C.  I’d probably just write my own Swift wrappers for it, if I were to do it in Swift.  I’d suggest starting with the man page for `shm_open` and go from there.  Plus of course some googling.

Comment: Oh wait you said Linux. I think `shm_open` is a POSIX API so the man page on MacOS can help, but you should look it up for Linux.  Sometimes there are differences.  Linux may also have its own API.